# Mouse Over picture on VB and make it stay when clicked

Tags: vb.net

So I make a form like this

[Form1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sV70e.jpg)

The picture box will show neutral.png when form is loaded, so

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("Images\neutral.png")
End Sub
```

I make the image on picturebox1 change to x.png while mouse over and disappear when mouse leave, so

```
Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseEnter(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseEnter
    PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("Images\x.png")
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseLeave(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseLeave
    PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("Images\neutral.png")
End Sub
```

My question is how I make the x.png image stay on the picturebox1 when I click the picturebox1. Doing this

```
Private Sub PictureBox1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Click
    PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("Images\x.png")
End Sub
```

Doesn't seem work since the mouseleave event still have an effect.

Comment: It certainly works, but you are not understanding the behaviour properly. The `Click` event is closely-related to the `MouseEnter`/`MouseLeave` events (you cannot click without "entering" and eventually "leaving" the given control and thus you are also triggering the other events). Think carefully about what is happening and choose the most adequate events (there are many) to accomplish what you want. Eventually, you might limit the conditions under which certain event is triggered; for example: by relying on the global `Boolean` variable `dontTriggerMouseEnter`.

Comment: Use some public variable which will tell You is picturebox clicked or not, and, in `MouseLeave` and `MouseEnter` check for that variable. If it's clicked don't proceed code. For example : `Dim isClicked As Boolean = False`, then in `MouseLeave` and `MouseEnter` check : `If isClicked = False Then PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("Images\neutral.png")`. Under `PictureBox1_Click...` put code : `isClicked = True` and rest of Your code. Of course, You can set and unset that `isClicked` under `PictureBox1_Click`. In case if You want to remove that `x.png` if You click second time, ...

Answer (score 2):

There is example, from my comment

```
Public Class Form1

    Private isClicked As Boolean = False

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("images\neutral.jpg")
    End Sub

    Private Sub PictureBox1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Click
        If isClicked = False Then isClicked = True Else isClicked = False 'if You click again, everything back
        'isClicked = True 'in this case, when You click "x.jpg" will stay always
        PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("images\x.jpg")
    End Sub

    Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseEnter(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseEnter
        If isClicked = False Then 'picturebox isn't clicked, so show x.jpg ... otherwise x.jpg will be showed always
            PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("images\x.jpg")
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseLeave
        If isClicked = False Then 'picturebox isn't clicked, so show neutral image ... otherwise x.jpg will be showed always
            PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("images\neutral.jpg")
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Use some variable, in this example is `isClicked`. 
Always make checking under `MouseEnter` and `MouseLeave` is `picturebox` clicked or not.

By this example, You can click again on `picturebox` to, let's say, reset that `isClicked`, so You can have again `neutral` and `x` images.